# Which SSL certificate to use for non-financial application

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, certificate-authority

Based on the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/200722/should-i-host-my-entire-web-application-using-https), I'd like to secure my website using SSL. Now there are several types of certificates and I don't know which one to choose.

My application doesn't include any financial transactions or similar, I just want to make the login process secure. Therefore I'm tempted to choose the cheapest certificate I can get, but what I definitely **do not** want is that the user get's some kind of Browser warning about the certificate being insecure / unknown / whatsoever where he has to click "Trust" or "Continue" to reach my website.

So what is the simplest certificate I can get with the minimum requirement above? Looking at hosting providers, I see features like

- Validated Domain
- Validated Organization
- Validated Owner
- Extended Validation
- Different encryption strengths
- AutoCSR
- Green Address Bar
- SGC (Server Gated Cryptography)
- Security Seal
- Insurance (don't need that)
- ...

Thanks in advance, your answers are always a great help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any certificate that you can buy from any reputable vendor will make the browser warning go away on all major browsers.  You can even get one for free (with domain-only validation) from www.startcom.org.

Comment: +1 for startcom. We use them extensively for free certs when we want to go up one step from self-signed. It works well on almost all platforms. We have only encountered problems with some old symbian telephones.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy certificates are pretty cheap, and I haven't run into an issue with them not being trusted.  You certainly don't need to purchase an extended validation certificate, just a normal web cert will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine with the cheapest cert you can get.  We've used the low end certs from RapidSSL, Thawte and recently AlphaSSL with no problem at all.